# How to give the First image in a gallery a different class than the rest of the images - Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called "Photo" that belongs to a model called "Shoe". I using Carrierwave to upload multiple images.

**index.html.erb**

```
  <% shoes.each do |shoe| %> 
    <div class="shoe">
      <div class="gallery">
        <% shoe.photos.each do |photo| %>
          <%= link_to image_tag(photo.photo_file.url(:thumb).to_s), photo.photo_file.url.to_s, :class => 'fancybox', :rel => 'gallery' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Outputs this:

```
<div class="shoe">
     <div class="gallery">
        <a class="fancybox" href="../nike-kd-6-meteorology-2.jpg" rel="gallery">
           <img src="../thumb_nike-kd-6-meteorology-2.jpg">
        </a>
        <a class="fancybox" href="../nike-kd-6-meteorology-2.jpg" rel="gallery">
           <img src="../thumb_nike-kd-6-meteorology-2.jpg">
        </a>
        <a class="fancybox" href="../nike-kd-6-meteorology-2.jpg" rel="gallery">
           <img src="../thumb_nike-kd-6-meteorology-2.jpg">
        </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

But I want the first image of each gallery to be able to have its own class and the rest of the images to have their own class. Something like this:

```
        <a class="firstclass" href="../nike-kd-6-meteorology-2.jpg" rel="gallery">
           <img src="../thumb_nike-kd-6-meteorology-2.jpg">
        </a>
        <a class="fancybox" href="../nike-kd-6-meteorology-2.jpg" rel="gallery">
           <img src="../thumb_nike-kd-6-meteorology-2.jpg">
        </a>
        <a class="fancybox" href="../nike-kd-6-meteorology-2.jpg" rel="gallery">
           <img src="../thumb_nike-kd-6-meteorology-2.jpg">
        </a>
```

How can I do this?

Also I want each gallery to have its own unique id but when I try to add this:

```
:rel => 'gallery<%= shoe.id %>'
```

I get a Syntax error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<% shoes.each do |shoe| %> 
  <div class="shoe">
    <div class="gallery">
      <% shoe.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
        <% image_class = index.zero? ? "firstclass" : "fancybox" %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(photo.photo_file.url(:thumb).to_s), photo.photo_file.url.to_s, :class => image_class, :rel => "gallery_#{shoe.id}" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```